# Git repo fetching submodule repo faisl to fetch specific valid submodule for a given commit?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, github-pages

I need your advice on the following. I have a one repo which refers to another repo as a submodule. So when you checkout this main repo which contains the other  repo as a submodule. I get this error.
Fetched in submodule path  but it did not contain 737282d4e408c414e8fcca176aa805ebeb802db9. Direct fetching of that commit failed.

Ok I understand this basically there were wrong commits in the submodule branch and one of the developer rebased the branch to the point from where the wrong commits happened and pushed it to master. Now I don't want my main repo also to get those commits but I think it is still referring to those commits before the rebase or something. Please guide here clearly as to what to do in this cases? I don't want those changes and the rebase in the submodule was fine just want the main repo also to not get those changes and only retrieve what's there is master of that submoduled repo.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to keep both local submodule version and the rebased version by other developers. So you can add another submodule for the same repo in another folder for you to refer.

Assume the submodule repo’s name is `repo1`, so you already have a folder named `repo1`. Then you can add submodule by `git submodule add <URL for repo1> repo1new`. Now you will have a folder `repo1new` with the latest version of `repo1`.

When you are ready to get the latest version of `repo1` for `repo1` folder, you can use:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: Hi Marina thanks for the reply. Please read my query to this question below and let know what you suggest.

Comment: @user3650632  Yes, you can use `git submodule update --init` to update the submodule to latest version.

Comment: @user3650632 did the answer help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 0):

MSFT 
Thanks for the reply. Basically I don't want to keep the local submodule version. By that I mean that I want to only keep the rebased version and want that if the other repo which uses this submodule fetches code for this submodule during checkout it should get the latest rebased version which is committed to master. The commits which were done should be just ignored and the developer can take another copy from the point where it was rebased and the module which refers this submodule should also fetch from that very point not the earlier commits. I hope this was clear?
So shall I do a git submodule update --init from where?